# getFields of base class instead of instanciated one

Tags: java, reflection

Say I have the following class inheritance structure:

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
      setDefault();
    }

    public void setDefault()
    {
      Field[] Fields = this.getClass().getFields();
        for ( Field F : Fields )
        {
         // perform some initialization per field class
         if ( MyObject.class.isAssignableFrom( F.getType() ))
         {
             ( (MyObject) f.get(this)).setValue(0);
         }
         // ...
        }
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal
{
   public Cat()
   {
      super();
      setDefault();
   }     
}

public class Kitten extends Cat
{
   public MyObject myobject1 = new MyObject();

   public Kitten()
   {
     super();
     setDefault();
   }
}
```

As I instanciate a `Kitten` object, I run in the `setDefault()` method of the parent class `Animal` wihtout having instanciate the `myobject1` member. I run then in a `NullPointerException` as it try to initialize it.

Would there be a way of getting the base class type in each `setDefault()` call?
That is when being in the `Animal` class the `this.getClass()` (or so would yield `Animal`, in the `Cat`class would yield `Cat`. This in order to set the default values only from parent class to child classes step by step.

Do you have any other set up I can apply?

Of course, I can add a test to check if the field is not null but that's not the point. I would like to set the defaults to the fields only of each class `setDefault`calls.

I cannot change the classes hierarchy nor the member's declarations places.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood what you are asking is to do `setDefault` method that will take `getClass` and will get the class it is in, meaning that the `setDefault` in `Animal` class will set only the fields of `Animal`.

if that is what you are asking then the answer is you don't need to do `getClass`, you can just set the default values of the class's members. you have permissions to change them because they are in your class.

also, you can override the `setDefault` method, change the values in each class in the hierarchy and call the parent function so every member is set

Comment: You are right indeed. But in my case the `setDefault` of the `Animal` class is the generic method for setting a default value to the `MyObject` instances. I just want to set the values for fields that are **declared** at the level of the class but in the parent class `setDefault` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the setDefault() method in each Class.

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
      setDefault();
    }

    public void setDefault()
    {
      Field[] Fields = this.getClass().getFields();
        for ( Field F : Fields )
        {
         // perform some initialization per field class
         if ( MyObject.class.isAssignableFrom( F.getType() ))
         {
             ( (MyObject) f.get(this)).setValue(0);
         }
         // ...
        }
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal
{
   public Cat()
   {
      setDefault();
   }  

   @Override
   public void setDefault() {
       // do some special things
   }
}

public class Kitten extends Cat
{
   public MyObject myobject1 = new MyObject();

   public Kitten()
   {
       setDefault();
   }

   @Override
   public void setDefault() {
       // do some special things
   }
}
```

Comment: That's actualy what is done ;-) But then the base `setDefault` would still try to initialize the `MyObject` member which is not yet instanciated... :-$

Comment: ok, then you have to delete the line with the super() - call.